# Concatinate Link and action in mDataProp

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I m using Jquery Datatable serverside pagination. There is a property `deviceMacAddress`. When i was using `display:table` earlier, then i was making `deviceMacAddress` a hyperlink having an action like :

```
      <display:column title="Mac Address" media="html" style="text-align:center;">
        <s:url id="deviceInfoByMac" action="fetchMacSummaryPage">  
            <s:param name="deviceMacAddress" value="%{#attr.row.deviceMacAddress}" />  
        </s:url>  
        <s:a href="%{deviceInfoByMac}" style="color: mediumblue;">
            <s:property value="%{#attr.row.deviceMacAddress}"/>
        </s:a>
    </display:column>
```

And Now as I am using `datatable`, so I just getting the value of `deviceMacAddress` in `aoColumns` like :

```
"aoColumns": [ { "mDataProp": "deviceMacAddress"},
                           { "mDataProp": "deviceName"},
                           { "mDataProp": "facilityName"},
                           { "mDataProp": "type"},
                           { "mDataProp": "language"},
                           { "mDataProp": "target"},
                           { "mDataProp": "status"},
                           { "mDataProp": "dateProcessed"} ]
```

and my jsp file has only headers for these columns like :

```
        <table id="row">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mac Address</th>
                    <th>Device Name</th>
                    <th>Facility</th>
                    <th>Module</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Resource Requested</th>
                    <th>Email Status</th>
                    <th>Email Sent On</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Now I wonder, how i can make a hyperlink of `deviceMacAddress` using this `datatable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [Here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) , `mRender` is the solution for what i was wondering.

```
// Use as a function to create a link from the data source
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [ 0 ],
      "mData": "download_link",
      "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
        return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
      }
    } ]
  } );
} );
```